# Piecemaker flash element won't work with almost same configuration as demo

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I had a working version of Piecemaker flash slider on my site. After tinkering with the theme the slider stoped working. Trying to track down the problem i've setup an almost exact enviroment as [the demo](http://www.modularweb.net/showcase/piecemaker2/) with no success.

I've checked that all the links are working, but i haven't been able to make the slide work again.

here's the link: http://www.aquaeliteevents.com/wordpress/?page_id=1430

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the XML was referencing resources from a different subdomain, once i configured the wordpress to appear on the same subdomain the piecemaker worked again.